# Removing duplicates while loading a combo in HTML using a txt file

Tags: html, ajax

Below is my code to load the combo using a txt file:

```
$("#Combo1").change(function() {
    $('#Combo2').empty();
                $.ajax({
                url: 'File.txt',
                type: 'get',
                success: function(txt){
                    var value = [];
                    var txtArray = txt.split('\n');
                    for (var i = 0; i < txtArray.length; i++)
                    {
                        var tmpData = txtArray[i].split(',');
                        if (!value[tmpData[1]]) 
                        {
                        value.push([tmpData[1]]);
                        value[tmpData[1]] = true;
                        }
                    }
                    $('#Combo2').empty();
                    $.each(value, function(i, p) {
                    $('#Combo2').append($('<option></option>').val(p).html(p));
                    });

                }
                })
            });
    $("#Combo1").trigger("change");
```

Here on change of Combo1, this will be called. The Ajax is used to read the content of **File.txt** File.txt has a "," seperated two columns, out of which I am willing to print coulmn2. Given below are the contents of File.TXT.

```
A,31JAN
B,25JAN
C,31JAN
D,6JAN
E,6JAN
```

I was to load the above dates in Combo2. With the above code, I am able to ignore 31JAN. But 6JAN is getting repeated. In short, the value which is given at the last row gets repeated. Rest is fine.

Comment: I have further debugged the same and got to know that the last row when stored in array, gets stroed without double quotes. Anything to do with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var txt="A,31JAN\nB,25JAN\nC,31JAN\nD,6JAN\nE,6JAN";
var txtArray = txt.split('\n');
for (var i = 0; i < txtArray.length; i++)
       txtArray[i] = txtArray[i].split(",").pop();
var value = txtArray.reduce(function(a,b){if(a.indexOf(b)<0)a.push(b);return a;},[]);
console.log(value); //returns array
```

Also, give this a read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229821/9920079 :)

Comment: Above code return both the columns. When I check two columns, those are anyways unique. I want the uniqueness of column 2 only.

Comment: @Programmer The above code(my answer) returns unique elements for column 2??

Comment: I found the solution for my problem. The above code was returning column 1 as well as 2. I wanted only column 2. In by file I have added a ,delimiter at the end of column 2 as well. That has solved my issue, thanks.